# Prove that this sum could'nt be an integrer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

let $(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^{2}$ such that $p\wedge q=1$ ;
Prove that $\sum_{j=0}^{j=n}\frac{1}{p+jq}\notin \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Is $\land$ the $\gcd$?

Comment: For the case $n = 0$, you have $1/p = 1/(1)$ if $p = 1$, so your statement is not complete.

Comment: It seems this is under discussion at brilliant.org, https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/sum-of-reciprocal-of-the-terms-of-an-arithmetic-pr/ (I didn't sign up to read further, so I don't know what else is there).

Comment: There is some discussion of this question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39326/reference-request-unit-fraction-equally-spaced-denominators-not-integer --- have a look!

Answer (score 2):

This conclusion was first proved by Nagel in 1923

solution is too long. here is outline of  an elementary proof

Suppose $\gcd(p.q)=1$

1). $q$ is an odd number

It is easy

2). $q=2$

If $p>n$, ..

If $p\le n$...

3). $q>2$, $q$ is even

this is the most difficult part, we need a lamma:

**Lemma**    the least common multiple of $1,2,\dotsc,n$

$$ [1,2,\dotsc,n]<4^n$$

Comment: Isn't a lamma an animal?

Comment: Can you give me the proof of Nagel please ?

Comment: @Sherloekholmes I don't have Nagel's proof

Comment: Probably Nagell, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trygve_Nagell

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes

Comment: However , i'am gratful , thanks ^^